# How can I use insert into with multiple tables?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to insert data for multiple tables at once. I'm trying join but I'm new to this and I hope you guys can help me.

I got 3 tables `Malzemeler`, `Tarifler`, `MalzemelerveTarifler` - all have some kind of a relationship through primary keys.

[My tables columns like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taqJs.png)

My code looks like this

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Malzemeler.Malzemeİsmi, TariflerveMalzemeler.Gram_mL, TariflerveMalzemeler.Adet, Tarifler.Tarif_İsmi 
                                   VALUES (@Malzemeler.Malzemeİsmi, @TariflerveMalzemeler.Gram_mL, @TariflerveMalzemeler.Adet, @Tarifler.Tarif_İsmi)  
                                   WHERE Malzemeler JOIN TariflerveMalzemeler ON Malzemeler.Malzeme_ID = TariflerveMalzemeler.Malzeme_ID JOIN Tarifler ON TariflerveMalzemeler.Tarif_ID = Tarifler.Tarif_ID", con);

komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tarif_İsmi", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtYemek.Text;
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gram_mL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtGram1.Text;            
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adet", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAdet1.Text;
       
if (cbMalzeme1.SelectedItem == null)
{
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Malzemeİsmi", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Malzemeİsmi", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbMalzeme1.SelectedItem;
}
        
komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: You need a separate INSERT for each table.

Comment: You can't do this in SQL. you should use separate insert for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multiple `INSERT` queries, but you can create one `Store Procedure` and put your three `INSERT` or more in `SP` and call that `SP` just once from your code, and also you can use Transaction if it's important complete all `INSERT` data in three tables.

Comment: i guess that's the answer i'll look store procedure now . thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle you can make use of Insert all to insert into multiple table from single select statement.

I think you are using SQL Server ?